# Generating new directory string on refresh

Tags: php, mysql

Basically what I want to do is have my chosen directory change it's string every refresh. I was able to achieve a new download file string on refresh with a script while using MYSQL, but I have no idea how a new directory string would work.

Is anyone able to lead me into the right direction? What would I need to include.

Thanks, here's the scripts for the new download file string:

Download.php:

http://pastebin.com/TPvbWfCA

Index.php:

http://pastebin.com/b6LyPx0y

```
sql.sql:

CREATE TABLE downloads (
    downloadkey varchar(32) NOT NULL unique,
    file varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    downloads int UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0',
    expires int UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0'
);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "new directory string". Did you mean "generate a random directory"?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you followed this guide:
http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/creating-one-time-download-links/

You don't need special directories if you want to do that, because the key is appended as a get argument. But if you want it like that `/downloads/somekey`
 you can use Apache mod_rewrite to rewrite all URLs that begin with /download/* to download.php Have a look at the Google results for mod_rewrite for guides to do that.